# Can't see types from own activity in type browser

Tags: c#, tfs, build, workflow-activity

How can I get my own build activities to display the containing types in type browser of build workflow designer ? My activity dll contains a public class, which is used to transfer various properties between activities. So I set this class to be `InArgument` or `OutArgument`, depending on activity. But when I try to assign this type to a variable in type browser, my custom activity dll will not show up in the list of referenced assemblies.

I am working with VS2013 and TFS2013. The custom activity dll works fine for all activities dealing with primitive types. I can drag/drop the activity to workflow designer, modify the parameters expect for those arguments unsing this special type. In fact, the type is not so special at all. Just a container (strings, guids, one dictionary).

Any hint how to deal with own types in custom build activities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to the meta property.

[image]

If you look at the bottom of the template editor you should see an "arguments" button. In the list of Arguments you should see that there is a "metadata" property. If you select the ellipse you get a designer where you can map your property to where you want it to be displayed on the build process designer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't find this "_meta_" property in the property browser. Can you give me a little more info how to do this?

Comment: Should be better now :)